# Unable to send email from Django Rest framework application

Tags: python, django, docker

I am trying to send email via Django Rest framework application. The mail should be sent to the user who would register to our system using Gmail.

I am also using docker images `python:3.7-slim` and `MySql:5.6`

First I have created email configurations inside the Django project `setting.py` file as stated below.

```
# Email Settings.
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 456
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'steinnlabs@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*****'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = 1
EMAIL_USE_SSL = 0
```

This is how `view.py` file of application looks like.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import views
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.db import IntegrityError
from rest_framework import status
from . import models, serializers
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.core.mail import send_mail



    class UserAPIViews(APIView):
        """
        """
        def post(self, request, format=None):
            """
            """
            print(request.data)
            serialized_data = serializers.UserSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serialized_data.is_valid():

                try:
                    user_id = serialized_data.save()
                except IntegrityError as error:
                    message = f"Email already exist."
                    return Response ({
                        'error_message' : message,
                        'status' : status.HTTP_226_IM_USED
                    })

                subject = 'Eitan - Case Manager Account Credentials'
                body = f"Hi {serialized_data.validated_data.get('first_name')} Your case manager account is ready. Please use following credentials to login. Email - {serialized_data.validated_data.get('email')}, Password - {serialized_data.validated_data.get('password')} Thank You! Team Eitan."
                sender = "steinnlabs@gmail.com"
                to = serialized_data.validated_data.get('email')

                send_mail(subject, body, sender, [to], fail_silently=False)

                success_message = f"User has been created."

                return Response({
                    'success_message' : success_message,
                    'status' : status.HTTP_201_CREATED
                })

            else:
                return Response (serialized_data.error_messages)
```

I don't understand what is wrong with my configuration. Whenever I call this API user is created but `send_mail()` functions fails with an error.

```
OSError at /user/create/
[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using incorrect EMAIL_PORT i.e 456 in setting.py file. Gmail's EMAIL_PORT is 587. It works fine for me now.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a connection issue related to Docker based on [this question](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/7475).

```
 Check that smtp.gmail.com:587 is open to connection from your docker container.
```

Comment: How to open or check the open port of docker container

Comment: Maybe you can follow [this page to set up your port](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-expose-port-on-running-container/3252/5) : e.g. ```docker run -d -p 587:587 ```